# How to rotate rectangle around its center in LWJGL?

Tags: java, rotation, 2d, lwjgl, rectangles

As the question states, I would like to know how to rotate a drawn rectangle around its center.

I am currently using the following code:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();

    GL11.glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);

    this.setAngle(this.getAngle()+1);

    GL11.glRotated(270-this.getAngle(),0,0,1);
    GL11.glTranslated(-0.5,-0.5,1);

    GL11.glRectd(this.getX(),this.getY(), this.getX()+this.getWidth(), this.getY()+this.getHeight());

GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Now, the rotation occurs in a 2D space, but I can't seem to centralize the rectangle's rotation. Instead, the rectangle keeps rotating around the global point 0,0.

I think that I may have the rotation and translation setup incorrectly or in the incorrect order.

I would like not what is stopping this code from producing the desired output.
Any suggestions and answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should translate, then rotate. If you rotate first, you'll translate taking the rotation into consideration. So, if you rotated 90 degrees, your translation would also be rotated by 90 degrees. Try reversing the order of your operations.

LIBGDX lies close enough to OpenGL that the OpenGL tutorials can aid you with this sort of thing, fyi.

Also check out the [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) class as it hides some of this from you.